# I can't draw a table in a section in Infopath

Tags: forms, infopath

I want to draw a table in a section I added but when I try, Infopath draws a table in the scope of the entire form and not in the section even if the cursor position is in the section... Have you any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on your section and then select boarders and shading option, in Borders tab select desire borders. here is a [sample InfoPath 2010 Form](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9c328512bb163014&resid=9C328512BB163014!128&parid=9C328512BB163014!126)

Comment: I apology, I missed to test to draw a tab with the pencil when you click "custom table" at the bottom of the listbox. When I try to draw a table with this pencil, it draws the table all around my section and not into.

Comment: I finally find how to do a real custom table inside a section with the "Split" and "Merge" (don't know the exact translations from french) buttons.

Comment: @cocoggu your suggestion is good and your translation is correct. :)